# My fade in goes to all opaque for it goes to transparent

Tags: javascript, css, scriptaculous

So, I'm trying to fade in a transparent div, kinda like hulu does when you click dim lights... here is what i have:

```
  //show the bg
  new Effect.Appear('darkBackgroundLayer', {duration: 0.3});
```

then when my pop up is initialized

```
// create the div for background dimming


 if($('darkBackgroundLayer')){
   Element.remove('darkBackgroundLayer')
  }

  var transparentBG = document.createElement('div');
  transparentBG.className = 'darkenBackground';
  transparentBG.id = "darkBackgroundLayer"
  transparentBG.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(transparentBG);
```

and the CSS for the new div

```
.darkenBackground {
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 opacity: 0.7; /* Safari, Opera */
 -moz-opacity:0.70; /* FireFox */
 filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* IE */
 z-index: 20;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-repeat:repeat;
 position:fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
    }
```

but, currently, it fades in... all the way to a solid back, then jumps to the .7 opacity...

ideas?

Comment: This isn't jQuery. Looks like prototypejs/scriptaculous.

Comment: Even If this is JQuery, $('darkBackgroundLayer') won't work unless you use a prefix like #

Comment: Ive integrated this with the facebox, if that helps
http://github.com/defunkt/facebox

Comment: @jAndy - That's what clued me in to prototypejs. That is its way to get an element by ID. No `#` needed.

Comment: @DerNalia - I don't think you understand. The facebox link you gave is a jQuery plugin. The code you're using above is not jQuery code. It is prototypejs code. http://www.prototypejs.org/ and Scriptaculous code. http://script.aculo.us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing Effect.Appear to

```
//show the bg
    new Effect.Appear('darkBackgroundLayer', {duration: 0.3,from: 0,to: 0.7});
```